# Origin of the "Pas" in negations

Tags: négation

Why is french negation constructed with ne ### pas? I mean where does the "pas" come from? Comparing it with spanish, wouldn't it be more natural to have "je ne suis médecin" instead of "je ne suis pas médecin" and having to carry the "pas" everywhere?

Note:I am aware that there are other negations (ne ###  jamais, ne ### que ...), so please don't address your answers from this perspective.